# How to store the standard errors with the lm() function in R?

Tags: r, linear-model

All is in the title...
I know how to store the estimates but I don't know how to store their standard errors...
Thanks

```
> x <- runif(100)
> y <- 5 + 3 * x + rnorm(100, 0, 0.15)
> reg <- lm(y~x)
> 
> summary(reg)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.32198 -0.12626  0.02584  0.10873  0.31411 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  5.00931    0.03087  162.25   <2e-16 ***
x            2.98162    0.05359   55.64   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Residual standard error: 0.1499 on 98 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.9693,     Adjusted R-squared: 0.969 
F-statistic:  3096 on 1 and 98 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16 

> 
> reg$coef
(Intercept)           x 
   5.009309    2.981617
```

Comment: it is reg$resid

Comment: @user603: Thank you... but I am interested in the standard errors... not in the residuals...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check the object that summary(reg) returns. You find then that

```
> str(summary(reg)$coef)
...
> X <- summary(reg)$coef
> X[,2]
(Intercept)           x 
 0.03325738  0.05558073
```

gives you what you want. Or, if you calculate them yourself (as @caracal showed in the comments) :

```
sqrt(diag(vcov(reg)))
```

Comment: Another way, based on the `lm()` fit alone: `sqrt(diag(vcov(reg)))`

Answer (score 6):

Somewhere Doug Bates once mentioned that accessor functions are preferable, so I'd do

```
R> example(lm)   ## to create lm.D9 object
[...]
R> coef(summary(lm.D9))
            Estimate Std. Error  t value    Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)    5.032   0.220218 22.85012 9.54713e-15
groupTrt      -0.371   0.311435 -1.19126 2.49023e-01
R> str(coef(summary(lm.D9)))
 num [1:2, 1:4] 5.032 -0.371 0.22 0.311 22.85 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:2] "(Intercept)" "groupTrt"
  ..$ : chr [1:4] "Estimate" "Std. Error" "t value" "Pr(>|t|)"
R> coef(summary(lm.D9))[,"Std. Error"]
(Intercept)    groupTrt 
   0.220218    0.311435 
R>
```

and the key is the `coef()` accessor for the summary object.

Comment: Very true, accessors should be used preferably. I just always forget their names...

Comment: Why is this preferable if it gives the same result as the method given by Joris?

Comment: Better object-oriented behaviour---there are *lots* of modelling function returning differently organized objects. By providing `coef()`, you abstract that inner layer away.

Answer (score 2):

Following on @Joris Meys answer for how to calculate std. error manually.

```
#Std. Error = residual variance / variable variance =
sqrt(diag(vcov(reg)))

#where vcov(reg) = 
summary(reg)$cov.unscaled * summary(reg)$sigma^2

#where summary(reg)$cov.unscaled = 1/(variable variance) (diagonal of precision matrix) =
solve(t(x) %*% x)

#where summary(reg)$sigma = residual variance =
sqrt(sum(reg$residuals^2) / (nrow(x)-ncol(x)))

> x <- matrix(runif(200),nrow=100)
> y <- 5 + 3 * x[,1] + rnorm(100, 0, 0.15)
> reg <- lm(y~x)
> summary(reg)$coefficient[,'Std. Error']
(Intercept)          x1          x2 
 0.03842706  0.05494507  0.05243990 
> sqrt(diag(vcov(reg)))
(Intercept)          x1          x2 
 0.03842706  0.05494507  0.05243990 
> sqrt(diag( summary(reg)$sigma^2*summary(reg)$cov.unscaled ))
(Intercept)          x1          x2 
 0.03842706  0.05494507  0.05243990 
> x_ = cbind(rep(1,nrow(x)),x)
> sqrt(diag( sum(reg$residuals^2)/(nrow(x)-ncol(x)-1) * solve(t(x_) %*% x_) ))
[1] 0.03842706 0.05494507 0.05243990
```

For math detailed please check [Standard Error for a Parameter in Ordinary Least Squares](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/216335/standard-error-for-a-parameter-in-ordinary-least-squares) or [How to derive variance-covariance matrix of coefficients in linear regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68151/how-to-derive-variance-covariance-matrix-of-coefficients-in-linear-regression) .

Comment: Although implementation is often mixed with substantive content in questions,
we are supposed to be a site for providing information about statistics, machine
learning, etc., not code. It can be good to provide code as well, but please
elaborate your substantive answer in text for people who don't read this language
well enough to recognize & extract the answer from the code.