# Can I only use cross-validation when sample size is very small or do I still need a held-out test set?

Tags: classification, cross-validation, feature-selection, high-dimensional

I am trying to predict a binary outcome. My sample size is very small (n=160) and has a high-class imbalance (80:20). All the variables are highly correlated, and the dataset is high dimensional (the number of variables is 96, and the minority class has 32 samples only).

1. Can I only use repeated or nested cross-validation instead of using a held-out test set (20% of data) for the final evaluation?
2. Or should I use cross-validation for hyper-parameter optimization only and then do the final testing on the held-out test set?
3. What feature selection methods are appropriate for high-correlated, high-dimensional data?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Validation: Data splitting into training vs. test datasets](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/50609/validation-data-splitting-into-training-vs-test-datasets) Also see [this post](https://www.fharrell.com/post/split-val/). On feature selection, see [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/2306/28500) among many others on this site.

Comment: Thank you for all the useful links. The first link provides information on bootstrap resampling, but that does not answer the question that if I perform repeated/nested cross-validation, if held-out testing is still necessary.

Comment: The first two links also make the point that held-out testing is inadvisable unless you have tens of thousands of observations. You could consider your repeated cross-validation as an alternative to bootstrapping; see Section 5.3.4 of Harrell's [Regression Modeling Strategies](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/validate.html#sec-val-resampling). He suggests 50 repeats of 10-fold cross validation.

Comment: Thank you @EdM. I will check out that section. I am still a little confused. We do the hyper-parameter optimization with repeated cross-validation and use the same data/approach for the final evaluation as well?

Comment: In that case, a good approach is to use cross-validation for hyper-parameter optimization, then repeat the entire process (including hyper-parameter optimization) on multiple bootstrapped samples of the data. The "optimism bootstrap" allows you to estimate and correct for overfitting in your modeling process. See [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/64788/28500) and [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/442894/28500) and [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/373171/28500) for the approach.