# Covariance between estimates of slope and intercept

Tags: regression, variance, covariance, estimators

[image][image]

I wonder why the covariance between estimates of slope ($\hat{\alpha}$) and intercept ($\hat{\beta}$) is $-\bar{X}\times Var(\hat{\beta})$.

How can I derive this solution by not using matrix?

- I add a new picture of my solving steps. I tried to use the rule of variance - which is $Var(x+y)=var(x)+var(y)+cov(x,y)$ - to derive covariance of $\hat{\alpha}$ and $\hat{\beta}$.
  But as you can see, the final solution I got is something wrong. I can't understand why '$-\sigma^2/2n$' adds to $-\bar{X}\times Var(\hat{\beta})$.

Can you plz help me find the stage in which I made mistake...?

Comment: First show that $\mbox{Cov}(\bar y,\hat\beta)=0$.

Comment: See:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/127316/clarification-the-covariance-of-intercept-and-slope-in-simple-linear-regression

Comment: This question has been in various forms on this site. Like https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68151/how-to-derive-variance-covariance-matrix-of-coefficients-in-linear-regression?noredirect=1&lq=1, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/171125/correlation-between-ols-estimators-for-intercept-and-slope.

Comment: I added a new picture.. plz help me:(:(:(

Comment: Please explain us why none of the links can help you?

Comment: [![Found a more elegant way of proving the same.Hope it helps.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjEJy.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjEJy.jpg) Found a more elegant way of proving the same.Hope it helps.

Comment: Please type your answer as text, do not just post a photograph or screenshot (see 
[here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3176/)).

Comment: Please type your question as text, do not just post a photograph or screenshot (see 
[here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3176/)).