# Covariance of many simple regressions

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, covariance-matrix

Assume we have a true model of

$$Y=X\beta+\varepsilon,$$

where $Y$ is some outcome , $X$ is a $1\times p$ vector of covariates which have a (non-diagonal) variance-covariance matrix $\Omega$, $\beta$ is a $p\times 1$ vector of parameters, and $\varepsilon$ is the residual which is independent to $X$. We further assume that the outcome $Y$ and each of the covariates $X_i$ are mean-zero and variance-one.

I have the results of $p$ simple regressions of the form

$$Y=X_i b_i + e_i$$

where $X_i$ is the $i$-th element of $X$ and $b_i$ is the associated parameter of the simple regression model. (Note that in this case, the OLS estimate of $b_i$, which we define as $\hat{b}_i$ will just be the sample covariance of $X_i$ and $Y$.)

I am interested in

$$Cov(\hat{b}_i, \hat{b}_j)$$

for any $i$ and $j$. Note that this is different than the covariance of $\hat{\beta}$ (i.e. the estimates of a multiple regression model controlling for all covariates simulataneously).

Is there an easy way to derive this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to derive variance-covariance matrix of coefficients in linear regression](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68151/how-to-derive-variance-covariance-matrix-of-coefficients-in-linear-regression)

Comment: That question is not the same as the one I'm asking.  It looks like that link is asking about the VCV matrix of the estimated coefficients of a *single multiple regression*.  I am trying to figure out the VCV matrix of the estimated coefficients when you perform *multiple simple regressions*.

Comment: Do you know the correlation between the $X_i$?

Comment: Sure.  But even if you didn't, you could estimate it from the data, right?

Comment: Ok. Your question sounds very hypothetical - that's why I wanted to cross-check this point.

Comment: I've tried to frame the question generally, but it is based on a real problem I have.  I have the simple regression results of a million different regressions of the form I described above, and I'd like to be able to work with those results, but I need to know the joint distribution of these estimates.