# Deriving $\text{Var}[\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}}]$

Tags: self-study, linear-model, covariance-matrix

I have already read [How to derive variance-covariance matrix of coefficients in linear regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68151/how-to-derive-variance-covariance-matrix-of-coefficients-in-linear-regression#).

Assume we're working with the usual simple regression model, $\mathbf{Y} \in \mathbb{R}^N$, $X \in M_{N \times (p+1)}(\mathbb{R})$, $\boldsymbol{\beta} \in \mathbb{R}^{p+1}$.

So, we have
$$\text{Var}[\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}}] = \text{Var}\left[ (X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}\mathbf{Y}\right] = (X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}\text{Var}[\mathbf{Y}]\left[(X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}\right]^{T}\text{.}$$
Now,
$$\mathbf{Y} = X\boldsymbol{\beta}+\boldsymbol{\epsilon}$$
so
$$\text{Var}\left[\mathbf{Y} \right] = \text{Var}\left[\boldsymbol{\epsilon}\right] = \sigma^2I_{N \times N}\text{.}$$
Thus,
$$\text{Var}[\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}}] = (X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}\sigma^2I_{N \times N}X[(X^{T}X)^{-1}]^{T}$$
and since $X^{T}X$ is symmetric, it follows that its inverse is symmetric, so 
$$\text{Var}[\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}}] = (X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}\sigma^2I_{N \times N}X(X^{T}X)^{-1}\text{.}$$
I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: $\sigma^2$ is a scalar, why don't you take it out in front?

Comment: @JohnK Yeah, I've figured it out now. $I_{N \times N}$ goes away, you end up with $\sigma^2 (X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}X(X^{T}X)^{-1} = \sigma^2(X^{T}X)^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easier than I thought. Any matrix times the identity gives the original matrix, so we have
$$\begin{align}
\text{Var}[\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}}] &= (X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}\sigma^2I_{N \times N}X(X^{T}X)^{-1} \\
&= \sigma^2  (X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}I_{N \times N}X(X^{T}X)^{-1}\text{ since }\sigma^2\text{ is a constant} \\
&= \sigma^2 (X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}X(X^{T}X)^{-1}\\
&= \sigma^{2}(X^{T}X)^{-1}I_{(p+1)\times (p+1)} \\
&= \sigma^2(X^{T}X)^{-1}\text{.}
\end{align}$$