# Matrix and regression model

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, estimation, matrix, covariance-matrix

[image]

Hi, can someone explain the second matrix? and how to use K in this problem? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: I am about to write an answer for you. Please let me know if you are no longer interested.

Comment: @AntoniParellada I am still interested. Thanks! I think I've solved part A, not sure if it is correct tho.

Comment: I just posted an addition to my answer. I can show you with a code example if you are interested.

Comment: @AntoniParellada And I have another question, if I have SSE1 for 107 samples and SSE2 for another 98 samples. How to find the combined SSE?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *standard error (SE)* of the estimate of a given parameter is given by the corresponding value along the diagonal of the *estimated covariance matrix*. So, for example, in an linear model such as $\hat y= \hat \beta_0 + \hat \beta_1\,x_1 + \hat \beta_2\,x_2$, the variance-covariance matrix will be of the form:

$$\hat{\text{Var}}(\hat\beta)=
\begin{bmatrix}
&\color{blue}{\text{intercept}}& \color{blue}{X_1} & \color{blue}{X_2}\\
\color{blue}{\text{intercept}}&&&\\
\color{blue}{X_1}&&\color{red}{\Huge \cdot}&\\
\color{blue}{X_2}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and the **square root** of the entry in the red dot is the *SE* of the estimated coefficient of the variable $X_1,$ i.e. $\hat\beta_1$, let's label it $\text{SE}_{\hat\beta_1}.$

Now we need to build a *confidence interval* around the SE, which will entail calculating the degrees of freedom if the *t* distribution is used: ($df = \text{no. observations - no. variables + 1}$ (the $1$ comes in because of the intercept). Otherwise, with a large number of observations the normal distribution can be used, and at a $5\%$ significant level, we will use the normal quantile for $0.975=1.96$:

$$\text{CI}_{\hat\beta_1}=\hat\beta_1\pm1.96\times \text{SE}_{\hat\beta_1}$$

and, the key is that this confidence interval shouldn't include $0$ if it is to be considered statistically significant.

The rest should probably follow, and I will leave out given the self-study nature of the OP.

---

As for your less immediate question,

> can someone explain the second matrix?

referring to the covariance matrix, it is the result of the equation:

$$\text{Var}(\hat\beta)= \sigma^2\,(X^\top X)^{-1}\tag{*}$$

with $X$ corresponding to the model matrix (including a column of $1$'s), and $\sigma^2$ the variance of the errors around the mean of the predicted points on the OLS line (the noise), which is calculated as:

$$\sigma^2= \frac{1}{df}\sum(\text{residuals})^2$$

---

Notice, that this is not the covariance matrix of the variables, but of the estimated parameters. The covariance matrix of the variables is calculated as:

$\Large \sigma(A) = \frac{G^TG}{n-1}$ with $G$ being the mean-centered observations and $n-1$ corresponding to the number of observations minus $1$.

---

Here is an intuition: $X^\top X$ is essential in the orthogonal projection of the dependent variable $Y$ onto the column space of the dataset $X$, encapsulating the geometry of the dataset. The fact that this latter statement is true is **exactly** the intuition of the variance-covariance matrix between the variables! So we project... with $(X^{\top}X)^{-1}$, orthogonally,... and we amplify (or make imprecise) that projection on either side of the projection by multiplying it times the variance of the noise ($\sigma^2$) in Eq. $*$.

---

EXAMPLE:

```
> d = mtcars  # mtcars data set as an example (different car models and specs)
> names(d)    # names of the variables
 [1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear" "carb"

> fit = lm(mpg ~ qsec + wt + drat, d)  # OLS model 

> X = model.matrix(fit)  # Model matrix X
> XtrX = t(X)  %*% X  # X transpose X
> inv_XtrX = solve(XtrX) # Its inverse
> df = nrow(d) - 4 # Degrees of freedom
> noise_variance = (1/df)  *  sum(residuals(fit)^2) # Variance of the residuals (sigma)
> (cov_matrix = noise_variance * inv_XtrX) # COVARIANCE MATRIX ESTIMATES

            (Intercept)        qsec          wt        drat
(Intercept)   65.106939 -1.36710241 -4.10219392 -7.59148854
qsec          -1.367102  0.06845697  0.02786122  0.01545768
wt            -4.102194  0.02786122  0.45981653  0.59099800
drat          -7.591489  0.01545768  0.59099800  1.50538184

# Take sqrt of one of diagonal elements (e.g. variable "drat"):

> (SE_drat = sqrt(cov_matrix[4,4])) 
[1] 1.22694

> (summary(fit)) # Compare to its Std. Error for "drat" value:

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  11.3945     8.0689   1.412  0.16892    
qsec          0.9462     0.2616   3.616  0.00116 ** 
wt           -4.3978     0.6781  -6.485 5.01e-07 ***
drat          1.6561     1.2269   1.350  0.18789    

> (CI_drat = coef(fit)[4] + c(1,-1) * qt(0.975,df) * SE_drat) # Its CI
[1]  4.1694177 -0.8571278

> matrix=cbind(d$qsec,d$wt,d$drat) # Compare now to the covariance matrix of the i.v.'s:
> (cov(matrix))
            [,1]       [,2]        [,3]
[1,]  3.19316613 -0.3054816  0.08714073
[2,] -0.30548161  0.9573790 -0.37272073
[3,]  0.08714073 -0.3727207  0.28588135

> var(matrix[,3]) # And you can match with the variance of "drat".
[1] 0.2858814
```

Comment: Isn't the diagonal the variance of these three variables?

Comment: @J.doe Are you comfortable with R? Let me append the answer.

Comment: I've inserted a pic I found in the question. Is the pic correct? I used that to construct a t test and then get the answer.

Comment: So I'll be able to find a new one and the diagonal of the new matrix is the variance of those three variables?

Comment: @J.doe Take a look at the output of the matrices in my code (posted in the answer), and the correspondence to the output of the summary for the regression model. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

First, the $K$ in this question refers to the number of $\beta$ coefficients ($\beta_1, \beta_2$), not including the intercept ($\beta_0$).

The second matrix is the so called [Sample Covariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_mean_and_covariance) matrix, of $\hat{{\bf \beta}}$. It's elements are $Cov(\hat{\beta_i}, \hat{\beta_j})$ for all i, j.

Notes:

1. For $i=j$, $Cov(\hat{\beta_i}, \hat{\beta_i}) = Var(\hat{\beta_i})$
2. For $i \ne j$, $Cov(\hat{\beta_i}, \hat{\beta_j}) = Cov(\hat{\beta_j}, \hat{\beta_i})$ which is why its symmetric.
3. See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68151/how-to-derive-variance-covariance-matrix-of-coefficients-in-linear-regression) for more detail

Think about how you can use the covariance matrix in estimating the standard error for $\hat{\beta_i}$ in your confidence intervals.