# Obtain covariance matrix with regression results

Tags: regression, covariance

I have regression results as follows:

[image: Regression results]

I also ran a variance-covariance matrix that output the following:

[image: variancecovar]

It's clear that squaring the standard errors provides the variance on the diagonal.  With just this, however, can you calculate the .000027, or the covariance of a and b?

Comment: Do you want to know what to use the covariance for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. You've stated the result back-to-front. The SE is the square root of the main diagonal of the covariance matrix of parameter estimates. You need to start with the covariance matrix of parameter estimates, rather than start with the standard errors.

You can find the formula for the covariance matrix of parameter estimates for OLS [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/68151/12833).