# Optimum approximate theory D-Optimal design

Tags: r, optimization, experiment-design, fractional-factorial

I am using optFederov, from package AlgDesign, to create D-Optimial designs. However, I am a bit confused on what measure to use as efficiency measure. I'd like to use D-Optimal but I don't know which one is exactly. In the vignette of the package they explain that the determinant of the design is 3.675919 and the optimum approximate theory D is 3.8 making this design about 97% efficient.

**1.-** But how does he come up with this 3.8? How can I compute it?

**2.-** When and why should I use D, Ge and Dea?

accoring to the manual D is:

*The kth root of the generalized variance: det(M)^(1/k), where det(M) is the determinant of the normalized dispersion matrix M – i.e. M=Z'Z/n, where Z=X[rows,]*

[image]

Answer (score 4):

OK, this is a bit complicated, but i will try to explain some issues here.

1. First of all, you need to know that you can calculate the
   theoretical (i.e. the maximum possible) and practically obtained
   (i.e. the ones that you get in a given configuration of cards and
   their sets) values for D-efficiency. The "quality" of the plan (for
   example in DCE method) is assessed with these coefficients, where
   the practical and theoretical value give information about the
   extent to which the reduced (partial) card plan will give you similar
   possibilities of calculating statistical coefficients on the results
   obtained by full plan method. The case is therefore very
   complicated; here we have a plan that allows us to "theoretically
   obtain D = 3.8" and practical D for a specific variant, D = 3.68,
   which gives an approximate percentage result of 3.38 / 3.80 = 97% of
   the plan effectiveness.
2. The most complicated issue is obtaining the maximum theoretical
   plan, or in other words, the maximum D for a particular plan. The
   calculation of the maximum D is related to how many main effects and
   interaction effects in the resulting analysis plan then we want to use.
   There are many examples of such information obtaining, but all of
   them are very illegible. Why? Well - we do not know what analysis
   plan the researcher set up for himself and for what plan he
   calculated the maximum possible D that could be obtained. In the
   example above, we can create a matrix only for main effects, for
   interactive effects, or for first or second order interactive
   effects. The maximum value of D will vary depending on these
   findings. I admit that I do not know for what plan this indicator
   was obtained and I hope that someone has figured out this example
   with D = 3.8.
3. Anyway - the matter is complicated by the fact that different
   programs have different algorithms for measuring D and often the
   same plans in R or other software will give completely different D
   and other indicators. The reason is often an encoding issue:
   orthogonal encoding, dummy encoding, or effect encoding changes the
   practical D values (you will get different wr values if you encode
   your data -1, 0 and 1 than if you encode them 1 2 and 3) ... which
   should be interpreted in the context of theoretical D ... which in
   turn depends on the size of your research plan of analyzes.
4. Due to this chaos, for some time published articles do not interpret
   D or other indicators, but simply give their raw values. Instead,
   the researcher tries to justify somehow the research plan he chooses
   and maximize the practically obtained indicators simply for such a
   plan. Now it's time for the R exercise in the example above.

For Your example we got in R

```r
library(AlgDesign)
dat <- gen.factorial(5, 3)
des <- optFederov(~ quad(.), dat, nTrials=15, evaluateI=TRUE)
des$D
```

which should give us the value of d

```r
[1] 3.675919
```

Knowing that

> 1. The D-efficiency values are a function of the number of points in
>    the design, the number of independent variables in the model, and the
>    maximum standard error for prediction over the design points.

and

> The best design is the one with the highest D-efficiency. Other
> reported efficiencies (e.g. A, G, I) help choose an optimal design
> when various models produce similar D-efficiencies.

we can check all of possibilities and use best one. In "dat" variable we have full plan of 125 possibilities/cards/research conditions/whatever. So we can check any variant between 5 cards for `optFederov` (minimal number) and all cards used. We will create an array variable that will allow us to save all the possibilities.

```r
min <- 10
max <- 125
eff_table <- matrix(ncol = 6, nrow = max)
colnames(eff_table) <- c("nTrials", "D", "A", "I", "Ge", "Dea")
for (loop_num in min:max) {
des <- optFederov( ~ quad(.), dat, nTrials=loop_num, 
                  evaluateI=TRUE, crit = "D", nRepeats = 100)
eff_table[loop_num, 1] <- loop_num
eff_table[loop_num, 2] <- des$D
eff_table[loop_num, 3] <- des$A
eff_table[loop_num, 4] <- des$I
eff_table[loop_num, 5] <- des$Ge
eff_table[loop_num, 6] <- des$Dea
}
```

Counting will take a while. Check differences with nRepeats and without; In my opinion, we should always use multiple retry, which is with this option. Then we get the best possible configuration in this regard. In

```r
eff_table
```

You should get all informations for subsequent options for the number of cards. Something like this

```r
 nTrials D A I Ge Dea
(...)
 [14,] 14 3.704358 0.8132031 7.820313 0.893 0.887
 [15,] 15 3.675919 1.2555973 8.848874 0.775 0.749
 [16,] 16 3.666758 1.2910678 8.807469 0.742 0.706
 [17,] 17 3.667087 1.3115654 8.693003 0.704 0.657
 [18,] 18 3.674348 1.1586909 8.544911 0.778 0.752
(...)
```

You can now choose the best practical option for your research plan and compare the ratios. **Note: one can also get with this method estimates for the full factorial plan, which are the maximum values you can get at all with mentioned method. On this basis, you can decide which plan is the best ... and calculate the percentage effectiveness ratio in relation to the full plan.**

Hope that will help You a bit. Feel free to ask and comment on this.

Additional informations and issues:

- The D-efficiency values are a function of the number of points in the
  design, the number of independent variables in the model, and the
  maximum standard error for prediction over the design points. The
  best design is the one with the highest D-efficiency. Other reported
  efficiencies (e.g. A, G, I) help choose an optimal design when
  various models produce similar D-efficiencies.
  https://itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pri/section5/pri521.htm
- interesting example of D counting:
  https://legacy.sawtoothsoftware.com/forum/23896/calculate-design-efficiency-manually
- D-Efficiency definition and general formulas: D-efficiency is the
  relative number of runs (expressed as a percent) required by a
  hypothetical orthogonal design to achieve the same determinant value.
  It provides a way of comparing designs across different sample sizes.
  https://ncss-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/themes/ncss/pdf/Procedures/PASS/D-Optimal_Designs.pdf
- Other ideas about maximum D:
  [How to derive variance-covariance matrix of coefficients in linear regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68151/how-to-derive-variance-covariance-matrix-of-coefficients-in-linear-regression)