# How calculate variance-covariance matrix of coefficients for multivariate (multiple) linear regression?

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, covariance-matrix

How to calculate a variance-covariance matrix of coefficients for multivariate (multiple)  linear regression?

Something like (equation below), but for the multivariate case.

Being more specific I'm interested in equations for diagonal terms.

[image]

The question is **different** from:

[How to derive variance-covariance matrix of coefficients in linear regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68151/how-to-derive-variance-covariance-matrix-of-coefficients-in-linear-regression)

Because of the **MULTIVARIATE** regression case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to derive variance-covariance matrix of coefficients in linear regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68151/how-to-derive-variance-covariance-matrix-of-coefficients-in-linear-regression)

Comment: @Pluviophile, No. On the above link, it's a univariate case. My question is on the multivariate case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general equation is the same for both the univariate and multivariate cases,

$$
V[\hat{\beta}] = V[(X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}Y]\\
= (X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}V[Y]X(X^{T}X)^{-1}\\ = \sigma^2(X^{T}X)^{-1}
$$

This is unfortunately challenging to calculate. Examining $X^{T}X$ we see (assuming an intercept is included in the model),

$$X^{T}X = \begin{bmatrix} 
n & \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i1} & \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i2} & \ldots& \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{ik}\\
\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i1} & \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i1}^2 & \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i1}x_{i2} & \ldots & \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i1}x_{ik} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots\\
\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{ik} & \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{ik}x_{i1} & \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{ik}x_{i2} & \ldots & \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{ik}^2
\end{bmatrix}$$

which is symmetric, but does not have a clean expression for the inverse. Therefore the simple formulas for the univariate case are not available for the multivariate case.