How to estimate the variance of the regression coefficients via Variance-Covariance Matrix?
everyone
I am not used to the matrix algebra. I know the maximum likelihood method to get the point estimation of the regression coefficients well. However, I don't understand the mathematical method behind to get the interval estimation of the regression coefficient.
For example, if we construct a logistic regression model, how do we get the variance of the beta regression coefficients?
I searched the Internet and there are some discussions which mention the Variance-Covariance Matrix method. But what is the connection between the matrix and the variance of the regression coefficients?
My question is: How do we use the Variance-Covariance Matrix to derive the variance of the regression coefficients of a logistic regression model? Can you briefly post the steps and rationales of this method? Thank you very much.
You help is much appreciated.
PS: I am not a statistician.
Tom

See this answer where it says: “ This matrix holds the variances in the diagonal elements and covariances in the off-diagonal elements.” It’s in the context of linear regression, but it’s true for other models.

Thank you for the info. Although it is difficult for me to understand the whole steps, I have a preliminary understanding of the rationale, after spending an hour on the post. I will update after several days about my progress. Much appreciated!

@Edm How does this method apply for solving the same problem of a logistic regression? There is no error term in a logistic regression model.

The ordinary least squares formula is a specific case of maximum-likelihood estimates used in generalized linear models like logistic regression. See this answer, for example. In general, the variance-covariance matrix (vcov) is the inverse of the matrix of second derivatives of the likelihood with respect to the parameters. In logistic regression the likelihood function itself includes the assumed binomial variance (error) of observations. Coefficient standard errors are still the square roots of the diagonal elements of vcov.

Thanks. It's a little difficult for me to understand. Now I know how the expression of b comes in the form of the matrix. The next step is to understand why b has a normal distribution.

The sum of squared residuals (SSR) is: SSR = e^Te, which could be expressed by the linear regression equation. Then the best expression of the coefficient b is the one that makes the first-order derivative of the SSR zero. With this method, we have the equation b. Then we use the calculation definition of variance to solve the variance of b. So, finally, we have the variance of b.

In the first comment @EdM made, he mention the steps in this link (https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/86104/28500). But I would like to understand it step-by-step and I was stopped at this location:
$$
\left((X'X)^{-1}X'\right)^2 = (X'X)^{-1}X'X(X'X)'^{-1} = (X'X)^{-1}
$$
I don't understand how this conclusion comes. Could you explain it in detail small steps? Thanks

When I get confused with matrix multiplication formulas I think about the matrix dimensions and how to arrange them so that the matrix products make sense. $X$, the model matrix, is an n x p matrix where n the number of observations and p the number of parameters. Thus $(X'X)^{-1}X'$ is a p x n matrix. The only way that squaring it makes sense is if you multiply it by its transpose, giving the p x p matrix in the middle. $(X'X)^{-1}(X'X)$ is the identity matrix. $(X'X)^{t-1}$ is symmetric, so it equals $(X'X)^{-1}$.

Hmmm, I think the delta method is a much more easier method to estimate the variance of the regression coefficient. Say, y = bx, and we can rearrange the formula so that b = y/x = g(x, y). We have the variances for x and y, and based on the method of delta method for multiple variables, we could directly express the variance of b in variances of x and y, and the covariance between x and y. And because linear regression usually assumes the regression coefficient has a normal distribution, we can directly compute its confidence interval. What do you think, pal?

This might work for linear regression, but it's complicated, hard to extend to multiple predictors, and would end up with the same result: the coefficient variance-covariance matrix will still be $\sigma ^2 (X'X)^{-1}$. See this page. Also, unlike maximum-likelihood (ML) methods, your suggestion wouldn't extend beyond linear regression. Although there aren't closed forms for ML in most applications, there is for linear regression and the result is the same: $\sigma ^2 (X'X)^{-1}$. Once you learn matrix calculations, they can simplify a lot.

You're right. Let understand the matrix of variance-covariance first before we dig into the maximum likelihood estimation for variance. OK. $$((X'X)^{-1} X')^2 = (X'X)^{-1} X' X (X'X)^{-1} = (X'X)^{-1}$$ comes from the fact $$(PQ)' = Q'P'$$, and $$(A^{-1})' = (A')^{-1}$$. Additionally,$$(X'X)' = (X'X)$$

@EdM Hello, pal. I think I have a final question. See here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/657182/how-do-we-prove-the-variance-of-regression-coefficients-of-b-are-corresponding-t

Estimating a single parameter value
Even when estimating only a single parameter via maximum likelihood, the normal distribution of the parameter estimates around the true value is an asymptotic result, holding in the limit of an infinite number of observations. This answer shows how that asymptotic result can be derived from the central limit theorem or the mean value theorem. The normal distribution, if it holds, simplifies setting of confidence intervals and significance tests as they come directly from the properties of normal distributions.
There is no assurance that the normal distribution of parameter estimates holds with small sample sizes, however. Evaluating the profile of the likelihood as a function of the parameter value can be more reliable, although it requires re-fitting the model over a range of assumed parameter values. See this page for a summary of different tests for models fit by maximum likelihood.
This page shows, for the single parameter case, that the variance of the asymptotically normal distribution is related to the inverse of the Fisher information at the true value of the parameter. The Fisher information is related to the second derivative of the log-likelihood with respect to the parameter value. In generalized linear models the form of the log-likelihood depends on the assumed family and link function. Quoting from Wikipedia:

Thus, the Fisher information may be seen as the curvature of the support curve (the graph of the log-likelihood). Near the maximum likelihood estimate, low Fisher information therefore indicates that the maximum appears "blunt", that is, the maximum is shallow and there are many nearby values with a similar log-likelihood. Conversely, high Fisher information indicates that the maximum is sharp.

In practice, there's yet another approximation involved even in the single-parameter case. You don't know the true value of the parameter, so you approximate the true (asymptotic) normal distribution as centered at your point estimate, with the inverse of the observed Fisher information (at that point estimate) determining the variance.
Multiple parameters
This answer illustrates the extension of the single-parameter to the multiple-parameter case. The Fisher information is now related to the matrix of the second derivatives of the log-likelihood with respect to pairwise combinations of predictors. You use the vector of point estimates and the matrix inverse of the observed Fisher information matrix to estimate the joint (asymptotic) multivariate normal distribution of the parameter estimates.
The answer to your question:

... what is the connection between the [variance-covariance] matrix and the variance of the regression coefficients?

is thus as follows. Similarly to how the inverse of the second derivative of the log-likelihood with respect to the parameter leads to the variance of its estimate in the single-parameter situation, in multiple regression the matrix inverse of the observed Fisher information matrix gives the variance-covariance matrix. As for any multivariate normal distribution, the diagonal elements of the variance-covariance matrix are the variances of the corresponding coefficient estimates. The off-diagonal elements are the covariances between the estimates.
Form of the variance-covariance matrix
In multiple linear regression, the Fisher information has the simple form $X^TX/\sigma^2$, where $X$ is the design matrix and the true variance $\sigma^2$ is assumed constant for all observations. Its inverse gives the well-known formula for the multiple linear regression variance-covariance matrix, $\sigma^2(X^TX)^{-1}$. For binary data, McCullagh and Nelder show in Section 4.4 that the Fisher information matrix has the form $X^TWX$, where $W$ is a diagonal weight matrix related to the true probabilities $\pi_i$ for the $m_i$ observations corresponding to each row $i$ of the design matrix (and thus to the expected variance among observations). Unlike for multiple linear regression, there's no general way to simplify the variance-covariance matrix $(X^TWX)^{-1}$ to separate out the contribution of the design matrix $X$ itself.
Using the variance-covariance matrix
The multivariate normal distribution of parameter estimates in general has non-zero off-diagonal elements. To go beyond individual coefficient variances you need to take into account the covariances. That's necessary, for example, in a Wald test on multiple coefficients. It's also necessary when making predictions from the model based on new covariate values, as you need to apply the formula for the variance of a weighted sum of correlated variables to estimate variances for the predictions.
