How do we prove the variance of regression coefficients of b are corresponding to the variance-covariance matrix?
Say, we have y = b0 + x1b1 + x2b2
I understand the proof of var(b) = var(y)*(X'X)^-1
What I haven't figured out is: Why does the variance-covariance matrix arrange so. Why does not it have a different arrangement? How do we prove the positions of the variance and covariance of the coefficients in the matrix?
PS: the matrix is
\begin{bmatrix}
\text{Var}(b_0) & \text{Cov}(b_0, b_1) & \text{Cov}(b_0, b_2) \\
\text{Cov}(b_1, b_0) & \text{Var}(b_1) & \text{Cov}(b_1, b_2) \\
\text{Cov}(b_2, b_0) & \text{Cov}(b_2, b_1) & \text{Var}(b_2)
\end{bmatrix}
Why not this, e.g.,
\begin{bmatrix}
\text{Var}(b_1) & \text{Cov}(b_0, b_2) & \text{Cov}(b_0, b_1) \\
\text{Cov}(b_1, b_0) & \text{Var}(b_0) & \text{Cov}(b_1, b_2) \\
\text{Cov}(b_2, b_0) & \text{Cov}(b_2, b_1) & \text{Var}(b_2)
\end{bmatrix}

The matrix has to be symmetric.

Are you aware of the rules involving matrix multiplication?

@Kuku Thanks for the comments, and please guide me to the proof.

I guess this is a proof: http://stat.columbia.edu/~fwood/Teaching/w4315/Fall2009/lecture_11
